# how to subtract amount from total on checkbox action in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

i have created checkbox field for donation on clicking checkbox 25 rupees is added into total but on uncheck it, 25 rupees is not subtracting from total on checkout page in word press.

```
add_action('woocommerce_review_order_before_order_total','add_donation_checkbox');


function add_donation_checkbox(){


    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='donation' id='donation' checked /> Donation";

    ?>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            //$(".fee").hide();
            $( '#donation' ).on( 'change',  function() {

                if($("#donation").is(':checked')){
                        $(".fee").show();
                        //alert('checked');// checked
                        $('document.body').trigger('update_checkout');
                }else 
                  {
                        <?php $order = new WC_Order(); $total = $order->get_total(); ?>
                        <?php  $new_total = $total - 25; $order->set_total( $new_total );?>
                        $(".fee").hide();
                        //alert('unchecked');// unchecked

                        //$('body').trigger('update_checkout');
                        $('document.body').trigger('update_checkout');
                }       
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}

add_action('woocommerce_cart_totals_after_shipping','checked_donation');


function checked_donation(){


    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='donation' id='donation' /> Donation";


}


// Add tax for Swiss country
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','custom_tax_surcharge_for_swiss', 10, 1 );
function custom_tax_surcharge_for_swiss($cart) {


    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') ) return;

    $donation = 25;
    # $taxes = array_sum( $cart->taxes ); // <=== This is not used in your function


    // Add the fee (tax third argument disabled: false)

    $cart->add_fee( __( '#AlshCares Contribution INR 25 ', 'woocommerce'), $donation, false );

}
```